# hdiv org.hdiv.filter.ValidatorFilter cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Filter

Tags: java, servlet-filters, struts-1, hdiv

I'm trying integrate hdiv 2.0.4 with old struts 1.3.8 to maintain old system in security issues. but, when I integrated I got that - hdiv validator in web.xml cannot be cast to servlet filter. Any suggestions for this?

> SEVERE: Exception starting filter ValidatorFilter
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hdiv.filter.ValidatorFilter cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Filter
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Dec 23, 2016 4:46:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have some classpath problem or duplicated libraries.
Similar problem:
[ClassCastException: MyFilter cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119712/classcastexception-myfilter-cannot-be-cast-to-javax-servlet-filter)